# How do I add events to array elements?

Tags: javascript, events

My code

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
for(var i=0; i<boxes.length;i++)
{
    boxes[i].addEventListener("dblclick", function(e){
        this.classList.add("animateSize");
        this.style.width="2px";
        this.style.height="2px";
        window.setTimeout(2000);
    });
}
```

Initially I have only one box, then I create more boxes but when I double click any of the newly created boxes nothing happens, only when I double click the initial box the event is triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

PS. When I alert(boxes.length) after I've created, lets say 4 boxes, I get the correct length alerted(5=4 + 1 initial box).

Comment: You do realize, your for loop only runs once, right? it won't re-run when the number of `.box` elements on the page increases. JavaScript doesn't have that kind of binding built-in.

Comment: Yeah I realize that. I tried some other stuff but eventually got back to this because I didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trouble is your code only attaches event handlers for the matches that are currently loaded in the DOM. If this is on DOM load, no 'future' elements will have the event attached.

You could listen for a double click on a static container (I've gone for document) and make a check to see whether the element targeted had the class `box`. If so, carry out your code:

```
document.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('box')){
        var box = e.target;
        box.classList.add("animateSize");
        box.style.width="2px";
        box.style.height="2px";
        window.setTimeout(2000);
    }
});
```

Also known as event delegation.

Note that you'd want to change `document` for closest static container of your boxes.

There are other ways of course, like attaching your event handlers every time you add your nodes to the DOM.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gey7gzo2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of event delegation. Do this instead.

```
var parentElem = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].parentNode;
parentElem.attachEventHandler("dblclick", function(e) {
    var that = e.target;
    that.classList.add("animateSize");
    that.style.width = "2px";
    // (...) More code
});
```